# why I can not pop elements from character stack?

Tags: c++, stack

I'm writing an example of a stack using a character array in C++.
when run program it show 3 options. 1st for push, 2nd for pop and 3rd for output.
I do not know when I push character into string I cannot pop the the top value.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int top = -1;
char stack[10];
int n = 10;
using namespace std;
char push()
{
    string a;

    if (top == n - 1) {
        cout << "stack is full" << endl
             << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "enter value to push" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    // loop
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        stack[top] = a[i];
        top = top + 1;
    }
    for (int i = top; i >= -1; i--) {
        cout << "  " << stack[i] << endl;
    }
    return top;
}
char pop()
{
    char x;
    //  int l;
    //  cin>>l;
    if (top < 0) {
        cout << "stack is empty" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
        for (int i = n; i > -1; i--) {

            stack[top] = x;
            --top;
        }
}

int main()
{
    int choose;

    do {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "choose your option" << endl;
        cout << "1 for push" << endl;
        cout << "2 for pop" << endl;
        cout << "3 for print" << endl;
        cout << "-1 for exit" << endl;
        cin >> choose;
        switch (choose) {
        case (1): {
            push();
            break;
        }
        case (2): {

            pop();
        } break;
        case (3): {
            if (top >= 0) {
                cout << "All values in the Stack are " << endl;
                for (int i = top; i >= -1; i--) {

                    cout << stack[i] << endl;
                }
            }

        } break;
        }
    } while (choose != -1);
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know why I can not pop element from character stack.
I am trying but i cannot figure what is wrong with my code. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: pop isn't neither popping (its assigning something to top based on an incomplete compare) nor is it returning a value. I am surprised you didn't get a compiler warning for that last one, or did you? (You should always fix all compiler warnings, not only the errors). All in all your code is still messy and probably won't even compile

Comment: `if ( l == )` should be rejected by the compiler. `for (int i = top; i >= -1; i--)` means that -1 will be used to index the array. Doing `top = top+1;` (`++top`) inside a loop without testing every iteration whether you have overflowed is wrong.

Comment: When you run this the first time: `stack[top]=a[i];` isn't top equal to -1?

Answer (score 0):

```
else
{
    char s[10]{};
    stack[top] = s[top];
    top = top - 1;
}
```

This pop method can pop one by one in your code.

But I don't know why you write and erase values ​​at -1 index.

And the fact that there are no errors is even more surprising.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
int top = -1;
char stack[10];
int n = 10;
using namespace std;
int push()
{
    string a;

    if (top == n - 1)
    {
        cout << "stack is full" << endl
            << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "enter value to push" << endl;
        cin >> a;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
        top = top + 1;
        stack[top] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = top; i >= -1; i--)
    {
        cout << "  " << stack[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
int pop()
{
    if (top < 0)
    {
        cout << "stack is empty" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
        --top;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int choose;

    do
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "choose your option" << endl;
        cout << "1 for push" << endl;
        cout << "2 for pop" << endl;
        cout << "3 for print" << endl;
        cout << "-1 for exit" << endl;
        cin >> choose;
        switch (choose)
        {
        case (1):
        {
            push();
            break;
        }
        case (2):
        {

            pop();
        }
        break;
        case (3):
        {
            if (top >= 0)
            {
                cout << "All values in the Stack are " << endl;
                for (int i = top; i > -1; i--)
                {

                    cout << stack[i] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        }
    } while (choose != -1);
    return 0;
}
```

you don't want to replace the char to delete the char
if you want to use the delete operator

for this pop operation just decrement the top value

and I put top increment before value assignment so it prevents putting the value in -1 index